# javascript solution to make variable absolute positioned div, push down other content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JavaScript multi-step form that hides previous steps (which are fieldsets) and shows the next with `display: none;`, which must be absolute positioned for the right effect.

- The *problem* is that having it positioned absolutely takes it out of
  the flow, and doesn't push down the content below it.
- The *solution I'm trying to create* is to wrap the absolute div in a parent relatively positioned div, and then use JavaScript to set the parent's height to be that of whichever absolute div is visible.

Can anyone help me with the javascript?

Right now, I know I need something like this on the next button: var divHeight = ((document.getElementById('fieldset').offsetHeight) + 'px'); document.getElementById('variable-div').style.height = divHeight; but the first part of this is wrong because I can't get the fieldset by ID, I need to get the one that is display:block and I don't know how to do that

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: here is the (updated) jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4dk7/6/

Edit 2: solution found:
`var fieldsetHeight = $("fieldset").filter(':visible').height() + 'px';
$('#variable-div').height(fieldsetHeight);`

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing a demo, but I would create an absolutely positioned div, and put everything else inside of it.  If you have several elements positioned in the same place, put each of them in a div of the same class.  That way, the contents can push each other around.

Comment: Could you please start a jsfiddle with the relevant part of your code?

Comment: @jantimon Sure, here: http://jsfiddle.net/n4dk7/2/

Comment: @Bez_almighty which element is the div in question?

Comment: @raam86 in this updated fiddle, it is the div id= "variable-div". I put some test text below the form to see if it is pushed down, or covered over by the form. http://jsfiddle.net/n4dk7/6/

Comment: @Bez_almighty it is quite convoluted. Like you said since you use absolute position it is taken out of document flow. The wrapping div does not change it. What you CAN do is put a relatively positioned element inside an absolute position one to be part of the flow

Comment: well, I need the form steps to be stacked on to each other. I'm looking for a js solution to set the height of the container div (which is part of the flow) to that of the absolute div (which isnt part of the flow). Right now, I know I need something like this: 
`var divHeight = ((document.getElementById('fieldset').offsetHeight) + 'px');
document.getElementById('variable-div').style.height = divHeight;`
but this is wrong because I can't get the fieldset by ID, I need to get the one that is display:block and I don't know how to do that

Comment: solution found: `var fieldsetHeight = $("fieldset").filter(':visible').height() + 'px';
$('#variable-div').height(fieldsetHeight);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see that you found a solution. If you need some more ideas, here is a fiddle for you to look at:

Outside of next and previous

```
var mainDiv = $( '#variable-div' );
var currentFieldset = $('fieldset');
mainDiv.css('marginBottom', (currentFieldset.height() + 5) + 'px');
```

Inside of next

```
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
mainDiv.css('marginBottom', (next_fs.height() + 5) + 'px');
```

[jsfiddle.net/pertrai1/ydjm2/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/pertrai1/ydjm2/1/)